# Find all dependencies in a Java class

Tags: java, generics, dependencies

I'm trying to get all dependencies in a Java class, including classes used for generics parametrization and local variables types. So far best framework I've found is apache [bcel](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/). Using it I can easily find all fields, method arguments and local variables from byte code. Basically everything except of generics and local variables types. For example, from line `List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();` I can only find one dependency - ArrayList using `JavaClass.getConstantPool()` method from bcel. It can't detect neither List interface nor Point class. I also tried [tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) and CDA, unfortunately without success (the same results). Examining imports is not enough - I need also dependencies from the same package and I can't accept wildcards. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to do this at runtime from bytecode?  Compile-time?

Comment: I want to find all static dependencies (not runtime). Reading bytecode is probably the best idea for that. But I can try to parse source code as well (it just doesn't seem to be the best idea and I have not found any solution for that).

Comment: Not all the source dependencies need end up in the class file (generic types within the method, inline constants). Just look at class files in a decent text editor, or on UNIX `strings`.

Comment: I've just checked it and bytecode does contain everything I need. It contains type of every local variable and every type used for generic classes/interfaces parameterization. I just don't know how to read that data from code using bcel. Thanks for comments.

Comment: I think the best approach (if in runtime) is Reflection

Comment: @user2511414 Reflection is not enough. Using reflection allows me to inspect fields, methods signatures, interfaces and so on. It doesn't show me local variables inside methods. I needed every dependency, inluding those used only inside methods code. Anyway, my problem is already solved. If you are interested, look at my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've finally found solution. `ASM Bytecode Framework` is the right tool to use. Using official [tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) and right [example](http://cvs.forge.objectweb.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/asm/asm/examples/dependencies/) it's quite easy to get all needed dependencies. In the example there is already a visitor class `DependencyVisitor` which does what I want. To get right formatting I had to change only one method in `DependencyVistitor` example code, so it adds full class names instead of packages only:

```
private String getGroupKey(String name)
{
        //Just comment that block so you can get full class names instead of package only
        /*
        int n = name.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (n > -1)
        {
            name = name.substring(0, n);
        }
       */
        // Replace resource char with package separator char        
        packages.add(name.replace("/", "."));
        //packages.add(name);
        return name;
}
```

Looking at `DependencyVisitor` code you can easily understand what it does and modify it to your needs. Running it on my example class it gives me nice, useful output:
`[java.util.ArrayList, java.lang.Object, java.util.List, java.awt.Point, goobar.test.asmhello.TestClass, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.awt.Graphics, goobar.test.asmhello.TestClass2]`. It contains every class and interface I've used and every type used for generics parameterization.

Comment: perfect, haven't had such this problem before, usually identify by annotations, but this is cool, thanks

Comment: The example code has moved [here](http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fasm%2Fexamples%2Fdependencies%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2Fdepend%2F).

Comment: The example code is now on [Guthub](https://github.com/llbit/ow2-asm/tree/master/examples/dependencies/src/org/objectweb/asm/depend)