# Get all dependencies from an start point - Java

Tags: java, refactoring

We are dropping a huge part of the code.
But we need to keep all that comes from an start point.

```
Ex:
  RestFacade
        import Service
                   import DAO
                       import ...
```

There is a tool that goes through every class and get the name of its imports?
I would like to get something like this:

```
Must Keep:
    pkg.RestFacade
    pkg.service.ServiceX
    pkg.dao.DAOY
    pkg.entity.Address
    pkg.entity.address.xxx;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371748/find-all-dependencies-in-a-java-class

Comment: should be able to google out some dependency analysis software; making pretty graphs and all that.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a link as a comment, but you can use something like BCEL, ASM one of those libraries.

It is assumed that you do not have access to the sources code because otherwise you wouldn't need to ask and you can just look into source.

If for some reason you have the source code and want to sort it you can just make a filereader and get the first x amount of lines before a class declaration.

Comment: I have access to the code. 
I thought about this in order to simplify the remotion of useless code.
(All that is not in that list, should be removed)